# How can I get the cancellation_date field?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

First，i want to know if the user has refunded in my App.

So i find the `cancellation_date` field can judge it, and it can use by this method from `In-App Purchase FAQ`

> The appStoreReceipt is refreshed only in the following cases after the
>   refund has occurred - when there is a successful purchase of an in-app
>   purchase item, when the `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` call is used and
>   when the `restoreCompletedTransactions` is used to restore previously
>   purchased products.

but this method will call the iTunes Store login alert.

So i want to know if there is another way to get the `cancellation_date` field or another way to know the user has refunded?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to store the entire receipt on your server and refresh it with the `/verifyReceipt` endpoint to get the current state of the subscription. Even if you only refreshed the receipt daily it would prevent a user from getting much access to your app after a refund, and you could track them even if they didn't open the app again.

Here's a good post that covers device-side and server-side nuances of Apple receipts: [iOS Subscriptions Are Hard](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscriptions-are-hard-d9b29c74e96f)

Comment: We tried to get the server to refresh the receipt with `/verifyReceipt`, the server could not get the `cancellation_date ` field. But if the refund user have another iap action, then server call `/verifyReceipt`, the `cancellation_date` will appear. So can I get the `cancellation_date` field directly through the server?